# How do I make the selected option of a SELECT field the same another select field Onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a select field called TRIP ID whose options come from a database. I also have another select field called APS Weight which has three options. STA, STB, STC - but the values of these 3 options is actually numbers not STA, STB, STC. What STA, STB and STC is, is actually the InnerHTML of these select options.

My issue is that i want to select a TRIP ID right, then onChange the selected option of APS Weight becomes the first three letters of the value of TRIP ID.

```
 <select name="tripid" id="tripid" style="width: 300px"
        onchange="document.getElementById('aps').value=tripid.value.slice(0,3)">
```

[image: The Select fields]

I think my code isnt working because. The value of the options on APS Weight is actually numbers and not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help!

```js
const setAps = () => {

  const select = document.getElementById("tripid");
  const selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  const selectedText = selectedOption.text;
  const aps = selectedText.slice(0, 3);

  const apsSlect = document.getElementById("aps");
  const textToSelect = aps;

  for (var i = 0; i < apsSlect.options.length; i++) {
    if (apsSlect.options[i].text === textToSelect) {
      apsSlect.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<select name="tripid" id="tripid" onChange="setAps()">
  <option>- Select-</option>
  <option value="1">STAABC Trip Location 1</option>
  <option value="2">STCABC Trip Location 2</option>
  <option value="3">STCABC Trip Location 3</option>
  <option value="4">STAABC some Location</option>
  <option value="5">STBXYZ some Location</option>
  <option value="6">STBXYZ some Location 2</option>
</select>

<select name="aps" id="aps">
  <option>- Select APS Weight-</option>
  <option value="1">STA </option>
  <option value="2">STB</option>
  <option value="3">STC</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Bravo!!. Works great and thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the value of the selected option in the `$('#tripid')` dropdown with the text content of the options in the `$('#aps')` dropdown.

Here are two solutions (JQuery using [`option:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and pure Javascript using `option.text`).

**JQuery:**

```js
$("#tripid").change(function() {
  var val = this.value.slice(0, 3);
  $("#aps option:contains(" + val + ")").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tripid" id="tripid" style="width: 300px">
  <option>STA-1</option>
  <option selected="selected">STA-2</option>
  <option>STA-3</option>
  <option>STB</option>
  <option>STC-1</option>
  <option>STC-2</option>
</select>

<select id="aps">
  <option value=1>STA</option>
  <option value=2>STB</option>
  <option value=3>STC</option>
</select>
```

**Pure Javascript:**

```js
function update(value) {
  const dd = document.getElementById('aps');
  aps.selectedIndex = [...dd.options].findIndex(option => option.text === value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tripid" id="tripid" style="width: 300px" onchange="update(this.value.slice(0,3))">
  <option>STA-1</option>
  <option selected="selected">STA-2</option>
  <option>STA-3</option>
  <option>STB</option>
  <option>STC-1</option>
  <option>STC-2</option>
</select>

<select id="aps">
  <option value=1>STA</option>
  <option value=2>STB</option>
  <option value=3>STC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a data attribute to the options, you can refer the same in the onChange method.

```
<select id="aps">
<option value="0" data-value="STC">STC</option>
</select>

<select name="tripid" id="tripid" style="width: 300px"  onchange="document.getElementById('aps').options[document.getElementById('aps').selectedIndex].dataset.value=tripid.value.slice(0,3)">
```